# Inheriting from IntEnum: PyLance reports "Literal[...]" is incompatible with "property"

Tags: python, enums, python-typing, python-3.10, pylance

Here is the code that cause the issue. This class has lots of other methods but only this one is at cause.

```py
from enum import IntEnum

class Position(IntEnum):

    LOW = 0
    HIGH = 1

    ###   String representation   ###

    @property
    def string(self) -> str | None:
        """Return 'low' or 'high'"""
        if self.value == self.LOW:
            return self.LOW_STRING
        if self.value == self.HIGH:
            return self.HIGH_STRING
        else:
            return None

    @string.setter
    def string(self, abc: str):
        """Set the value from 'low' or 'high'"""
        if abc == self.LOW_STRING:
            self.value = self.LOW
        elif abc == self.HIGH_STRING:
            self.value = self.HIGH
```

However PyLance underline self.LOW and self.HIGH in red.

It reports:

```
Cannot assign member "value" for type "Position"
  "Literal[Position.LOW]" is incompatible with "property" PylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
```

As a precision, we are using strict mode.

Comment: Your example is not complete. Where are `LOW_STRING` and `HIGH_STRING` attributes defined?

Comment: (Not that it matters; you simply aren't allowed to assign to the `value` attribute. You'll get `AttributeError: <enum 'Enum'> cannot set attribute 'value'` if you try.)

Comment: Use composition, not inheritance. Something should _have_ a position. If something _is_ a position, it can't just change. A low position can't suddenly become a high position. Low is low; high is high. But an object can change its position from low to high.

Answer (score 0):

As @chepner alluded to, enum members are constants.  `Position.HIGH` will *always* be `1`, and the enum machinery will block attempts to change its value.

As an aside, the anti-pattern of `self.value == self.ENUM_MEMBER` will no longer work in 3.14.